# is it possible to send a current HTML document as a attachment through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending mail from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747038/sending-mail-from-javascript)

i want to send a email and as a attachment the current HTML page. Is it possible through java script to get the current entire HTML document and send it as attachment.

following is my code :

```
function isBillDateFilled(){
var billDate = global.getElementById('CIMtrek_RegWhseCo_BillDate').value;
    if(billDate.length==0){
        alert("Please enter Bill Date.");
        return false;
    }else{
        var formType=global.getElementById('CIMtrek_RegWhseCo_FormType').value;
        alert("formType : "+formType);
        if(formType=='Regional'){
            var underWeightAns= confirm("Weight Check" ; "Is trailer under 36,000 lbs?");
            var actBilledWt = global.getElementById('CIMtrek_RegWhseCo_ActBilledWt').value;
            alert("Reminder: Use Actual Bill Weight - which is "+actBilledWt+" lbs");
            if(underWeightAns){
                alert("Under Weight");
                //Send Mail
            }
        }
      }
}
```

i have commented Send Mail. this is the place where i want to get the current HTML page and send it as a attachment.

Comment: @WouterdeKort Please read the question fully and comment, It is not duplicate, I have not asked how to send mail using javascript but how to get the current HTML document using java script. If you are not able to answer it is well and good, No issue

Comment: you could get the `document.body.innerHTML` and send it as an escaped variable in your form, then on server side you could elaborate that string and generate an attachment

Comment: As commented by Fabrizio you could get the html code from innerHTML and then send it to server using ajax, however far more efficient way is to send back the values you need and generate the email attachement on server - since you have the initial page generated on server anyway.

Comment: You can't send email via client-side javascript.

Comment: Your title and question allures to sending emails in JS. You're running close to getting closed. You should edit to be more clear about your intentions. Your question to me is simply "how do I get the entire html for my page using javascript?".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go about this is to just build the content from innerHTMLs:

```
var base = location.href.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, '');
var html = '<html><head>';
html += '<base href="'+base+'">';
html += document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML; // some older browsers don't know document.head
html += '</head><body>';
html += document.body.innerHTML;
html += '</body></html>';
```

I added the base tag so you could use the HTML outside of your server context without having to modify all links and image paths.